# How can i install Clickhouse on a raspbery pi 4 with ubuntu?

Tags: clickhouse

Is there any special way to install click-house on raspberry pi?
I tried to get install with git source but in a middle, its getting stuck...
Expecting a step by step method to follow...

Comment: look at related links: https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/7302 and https://clickhouse.tech/blog/en/2020/pixel-benchmark/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CH CI builds aarch64 binary for every commit. You can download it

https://clickhouse-builds.s3.yandex.net/12470/e1e41d8a8d3e6b890509d45550b52f25fa5335f2/clickhouse_build_check/report.html

wget https://clickhouse-builds.s3.yandex.net/12470/e1e41d8a8d3e6b890509d45550b52f25fa5335f2/clickhouse_build_check/clang-10-aarch64_relwithdebuginfo_none_bundled_unsplitted_disable_False_binary/clickhouse

and make own .deb or .rpm

Comment: hi mate still i couldn't install it. can your please give me a location to download the deb file or do u have a ubuntu image which it is installed? I'm using 18.04\

Comment: No .deb packages. Only single binary.

Comment: Found it bro...
worked with 
https://clickhouse-builds.s3.yandex.net/12470/e1e41d8a8d3e6b890509d45550b52f25fa5335f2/clickhouse_build_check/clang-10-aarch64_relwithdebuginfo_none_bundled_unsplitted_disable_False_binary/clickhouse